# Custom UICollectionViewCell inside UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I followed the tutorial:http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/ to implement a UICollectionView inside of a UITableViewCell. How to I implement a custom UICollectionViewCell inside of the UICollectionView programmatically without using the storyboard? I just need a simple UILabel inside my UICollectionViewCell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, named it `CustomCell`, and implement the method `initWithFrame`, where you can add `UILabel` to your cell.
2. Register your custom `UICollectionViewCell`

   `[self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];`
3. Dequeue Cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

   `CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`